# PBI services Odbc.DataSource dynamic dsn name

Tags: powerbi, odbc, dax, powerquery, m

In PBI desktop file no errors, erro appear only in PBI service on refreshing

> **ERROR:**
>
> Query contains unsupported function. Function name:Odbc.DataSource

> **Parameter1**
>
> Mydsn ' as parameter

**used as text**  - not dynamic

```
= Odbc.DataSource("dsn=Mydsn", [HierarchicalNavigation=true])  ' no error
```

**as used us text Parameter**  - not dynamic

```
= Odbc.DataSource("dsn=" & Parameter1, [HierarchicalNavigation=true])  ' no error,
```

> **Odbc_dsn ' Query**
>
> = settings[Column2]{0} ' from csv

**from csv query**

```
= Odbc.DataSource("dsn=" & Odbc_dsn, [HierarchicalNavigation=true])  ' Query contains unsupported function. Function name: Odbc.DataSource
```

**directly from csv table**

```
= Odbc.DataSource("dsn=" & settings[Column2]{0}, [HierarchicalNavigation=true])  ' Query contains unsupported function. Function name: Odbc.DataSource
```

- No one of Privacy settings is not change anything, tryied all
  available ways. (change to none, private, organizational, public,
  disabling privacy settings and etc)

How to use odbs source DSN name from csv file?

Comment: which database server are you using? Is it a local server?

Comment: no, database running on other PC (ip)

Comment: @Dmitrij A couple questions: 1) what types of resources do the DSNs point to? Databases? Files? 2) Are the resources of identical schema? (If I drill into DSN 1, will the same table names, column names etc. as DSN 2?)

Comment: 1) nothing, only direct connection to IP and PORT
2) Yes DSn names same as created in ODBC data sources 64bit System DSN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dsn name can be only static and only string

Answer (score 2):

(Answer to be expanded with additional info provided - see comments on original question)

While I have never imported a DSN name through a CSV, your saying that it works on your local machine makes me accept that this is at least possible so we'll instead focus on issues with the gateway.

My first impression here as to why this might not be working is simply permissions and visibility.

Having worked with a number of PowerBI Service setups, the issue with an unrecognized ODBC DSN usually falls into the following issues:

1. Is the DSN setup as a system DSN?
2. Is the gateway setup as a LocalService Account vs PowerBI Gateway Host Account?
3. Does which user the gateway is setup under actually have permissions to the directory that the data source (or custom connector) that the connection depends on?

So:

1. Fairly straight forward: all gateway accessible ODBC sources need to be setup on the gateway host as system DSNs, not user DSNs. See your ODBC Data Source Administrator here:
   [image]
2. Confirm the On-Premise Gateway "Logon" User on the gateway's host machine? Generally I recommend going to Windows Services and making sure to use the "Local System account" (to inherit permissions) but just consider this during the next step of checking local permissions.
   [image]
3. **This applies to anything which is "self-hosted" on the local machine that is the gateway host**: Whichever account is hosting the powerbi gateway service must also be given explicit permissions to the local resources needed. For example, if you add a custom connector to the documents directory on the gateway host under *your* user account - make sure the PowerBI default user has access to that directory and file. I.E. File properties -> Security -> User permission etc.
   [image]

In my experience, 9/10 times one of these things isn't setup right.

Additional note - every time you upgrade or re-install a powerbi gateway host, you will have to change the service login account and double check all permissions. I don't know why but it overwrites that setting by default disabling all refresh until restored.

---

Edit:

After further thinking, I believe you will eventually run into the roadblock regardless - PowerBI Service's Gateway Data Source mappings are 1-1. After upload you will get this screen in the dataset settings:

[image: Dataset Gateway Mapping]

Which requires that the data source has been defined in the PowerBI service's settings:

[image: Gateway Data Source Definition]

I don't believe that it is currently possible to make that definition a variably composed string per user's request.

Comment: -have permissions to the directory that the data source (or custom connector) . WHAT is that, where i can find this folder?
- that the connection depends on?  realy dont understand what you talking about? I setup ODBC it not have any directory as saving in registry

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin I'm missing infos on bitness (x86/x64) as there are two ODBC Data Sources, one for each bitness. You have to use the one matching the bitness of application, that uses the DSN.